# Selenium 2.0 WebDriver: Clearing Session Data

Tags: selenium, selenium2, webdriver, nunit

Is there a way to clear out session data for a driver instance in WebDriver?  My code is written in C# (and NUnit), but I'm not picky on the language for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that the deleteAllCookies function works differently in different browsers. DeleteAllCookies will delete all session data in Chrome, but only cookies in firefox. I'm still looking for a good way to delete session data in FF

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you can delete all the cookies by calling `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()`.

Comment: I am suing Chrome , but for me it is not clearing form data.